# JavaScript String concatenation behavior with null or undefined values

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, string-concatenation

As you may know, in JavaScript `'' + null = "null"` and `'' + undefined = "undefined"` (in most browsers I can test: Firefox, Chrome and IE). I would like to know the origin of this oddity (what the heck was in the head on Brendan Eich?!) and if there is any aim for changing it in a future version of ECMA. It's indeed pretty frustrating having to do `'sthg' + (var || '')` for concatenating Strings with variables and using a third party framework like *Underscore* or other for that is using a hammer for jelly nail pounding.

**Edit:**

To meet the criteria required by StackOverflow and clarify my question, it is a threefold one:

- What is the history behind the oddity that makes JS converting `null` or `undefined` to their string value in `String` concatenation?
- Is there any chance for a change in this behavior in future ECMAScript versions?
- What is the prettiest way to concatenate `String` with potential `null` or `undefined` object without falling into this problem (getting some `"undefined"` of `"null"` in the middle of the String)? By the subjective criteria *prettiest*, I mean: short, clean and effective. No need to say that `'' + (obj ? obj : '')` is not really pretty…

Comment: +1 Agree, I was expecting the same behaviour (which now costs me lot of if condition that slows data my apps). I have an `R` background and in there you get what you said `paste0("a", NULL) == "a"`

Comment: Actually the behavior is exactly what I would expect. null and undefined are converted to their string representations which are different from the empty string, but it would be easy enough to write a function that looked at its arg and returned the empty string if it were null or undefined, and the toString of anything else.

Comment: @MikeLipper Easy enough but not native and no coalescence with this (no operator overloading in JS, hopefully). Coalescence is something great in JS for compact code and this advantage is broken by this behavior. You have to use workarounds. And if I ask the question, it is that this behavior is far from what I expect.

Comment: It's a nice way of letting you know that some value wasn't assigned an actual string value and/or lacks `toString` or `valueOf` methods.  I would imagine there are as many circumstances where you would want them to show as `null` or `undefined` as you would want them to show as an empty string.  Fortunately, I hardly ever run into this problem since I often concatenate strings with join (it solves other issues such as doing concatenations while using ternary (`?`) expressions).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> What is the prettiest way to concatenate String with potential null or undefined object without falling into this problem [...]?

There are several ways, and you partly mentioned them yourself. To make it short, the *only* clean way I can think of is a function:

```
const Strings = {};
Strings.orEmpty = function( entity ) {
    return entity || "";
};

// usage
const message = "This is a " + Strings.orEmpty( test );
```

Of course, you can (and should) change the actual implementation to suit your needs. And this is already why I think this method is superior: it introduced encapsulation.

Really, you only have to ask what the "prettiest" way is, if you don't have encapsulation. You ask yourself this question because you *already know* that you are going to get yourself into a place where you cannot change the implementation anymore, so you want it to be perfect right away. But that's the thing: requirements, views and even envrionments change. They evolve. So why not allow yourself to change the implementation with as little as adapting one line and perhaps one or two tests?

You could call this cheating, because it doesn't really answer how to implement the actual logic. But that's my point: it doesn't matter. Well, maybe a little. But really, there is no need to worry because of how simple it would be to change. And since it's not inlined, it also looks a lot prettier – whether or not you implement it this way or in a more sophisticated way.

If, throughout your code, you keep repeating the `||` inline, you run into two problems:

- You duplicate code.
- And because you duplicate code, you make it hard to maintain and change in the future.

And these are two points commonly known to be anti-patterns when it comes to high-quality software development.

Some people will say that this is too much overhead; they will talk about performance. It's non-sense. For one, this barely adds overhead. If this is what you are worried about, you chose the wrong language. Even jQuery uses functions. People need to get over micro-optimization.

The other thing is: you can use a code "compiler" = minifier. Good tools in this area will try to detect which statements to inline during the compilation step. This way, you keep your code clean and maintainable and can still get that last drop of performance if you still believe in it or really do have an environment where this matters.

Lastly, have some faith in browsers. They will optimize code and they do a pretty darn good job at it these days.

Comment: You're answer is perfect as it seems to be the more efficient and elegant way to deal with this problem. I accept it even if it doesn't answer to the two first points that are darn ones. @Oriol also deserved some merit because he also answers those missing points.

Comment: It's ironic that you warn about duplicated code while presenting an approach that leads to duplicated code.

Comment: @zeroflagL you are free to encapsulate even more on a use case abstraction level. But I don't know about use cases involved. I am presenting an idea.

Answer (score 121):

You can use `Array.prototype.join` to ignore `undefined` and `null`:

```js
['a', 'b', void 0, null, 6].join(''); // 'ab6'
```

According to the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.5):

> If *element* is `undefined` or `null`, Let *next* be the empty String;
>   otherwise, let *next* be ToString(*element*).

---

Given that,

- > What is the history behind the oddity that makes JS converting `null` or `undefined` to their string value in `String` concatenation?

  In fact, in some cases, the current behavior makes sense.

  ```
  function showSum(a,b) {
      alert(a + ' + ' + b + ' = ' + (+a + +b));
  }
  ```

  For example, if the function above is called without arguments, `undefined + undefined = NaN` is probably better than  `+  = NaN`.

  In general, I think that if you want to insert some variables in a string, displaying `undefined` or `null` makes sense. Probably, Eich thought that too.

  Of course, there are cases in which ignoring those would be better, such as when joining strings together. But for those cases you can use `Array.prototype.join`.
- > Is there any chance for a change in this behavior in future ECMAScript versions?

  Most likely not.

  Since there already is `Array.prototype.join`, modifying the behavior of string concatenation would only cause disadvantages, but no advantages. Moreover, it would break old codes, so it wouldn't be backwards compatible.
- > What is the prettiest way to concatenate String with potential `null` or `undefined`?

  `Array.prototype.join` seems to be the simplest one. Whether it's the prettiest or not may be opinion-based.

Comment: I agree that this is the best answer to the third part of the question. I wanted to upvote, but the question has two other parts. Then again, I imagine this should just be posted as three different questions.

Comment: @Cory True, I have completed the answer.

Comment: *"You can use Array.prototype.join to ignore undefined and null"* - it's worth pointing out that this only works as desired if you're using an empty string as your `join` arg.

Comment: Add `.trim()` after `.join()` and it will remove leading/trialing spaces. (In case of joining using space). Similarly other types of chars can be removed

Comment: Using this in conjunction with string interpolation for url formulation:  `let url = \`${AREA_ROOT}/Projects/${[projectId].join('')}\``

Answer (score 16):

#### The ECMA Specification

Just to flesh out the reason it behaves this way in terms of the spec, this behavior has been present since [version one](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf).  The definition there and in 5.1 are semantically equivalent, I'll show the 5.1 definitions.

[Section 11.6.1: The Addition operator ( + )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1)

> The addition operator either performs string concatenation or numeric
>   addition.
>
> The production *AdditiveExpression* : *AdditiveExpression* +
>   *MultiplicativeExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 2. Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating
>      MultiplicativeExpression.
> 4. Let *rval* be GetValue(*rref*).
> 5. Let *lprim* be
>      ToPrimitive(*lval*).
> 6. Let *rprim* be ToPrimitive(*rval*).
> 7. If Type(*lprim*) is
>      String or Type(*rprim*) is String, then
>      a. Return the String that is the
>      result of concatenating ToString(*lprim*) followed by ToString(*rprim*)
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to
>      ToNumber(*lprim*) and ToNumber(*rprim*). See the Note below 11.6.3.

So, if either value ends up being a `String`, then `ToString` is used on both arguments (line 7) and those are concatenated (line 7a).  `ToPrimitive` returns all non-object values unchanged, so `null` and `undefined` are untouched:

[Section 9.1 ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1)

> The abstract operation ToPrimitive takes an *input* argument and an optional argument *PreferredType*. The abstract operation ToPrimitive converts its *input* argument to a non-Object type ...  Conversion occurs according to Table 10:

For all non-`Object` types, including both `Null` and `Undefined`, `[t]he result equals the input argument (no conversion).`  So `ToPrimitive` does nothing here.

Finally, [Section 9.8 ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)

> The abstract operation ToString converts its argument to a value of type String according to Table 13:

Table 13 gives `"undefined"` for the `Undefined` type and `"null"` for the `Null` type.

#### Will it change? Is it even an "oddity"?

As others have pointed out, this is very unlikely to change as it would break backward compatibility (and bring no real benefit), even more so given that this behavior is the same since the 1997 version of the spec.  I would also not really consider it an oddity.

If you were to change this behavior, would you change the definition of `ToString` for `null` and `undefined` or would you special-case the addition operator for these values?  `ToString` is used many, many places throughout the spec and 
`"null"` seems like an uncontroversial choice for representing `null`.  Just to give a couple of examples, in Java `"" + null` is the string `"null"` and in Python `str(None)` is the string `"None"`.

#### Workaround

Others have given good workarounds, but I would add that I doubt you want to use `entity || ""` as your strategy since it resolves `true` to `"true"` but `false` to `""`.  The array join in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26767082/1464861) has the more expected behavior, or you could change the implementation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26767630/1464861) to check `entity == null` (both `null == null` and `undefined == null` are true).

Answer (score 16):

**Use coalescing - syntax is `??`**

Examples, can test in your browser console:

- `"Hello " + (null ?? "")`
- `"Hello " + (undefined ?? "")`

Both will yield: `'Hello '`

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm answering this question: `What is the prettiest way to concatenate String with potential null or undefined object without falling into this problem`. My answer does not contain a rhetorical question - ?? is literally the syntax...

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help it might help you to make the difference between (exaggerated) prose punctuation and code syntax more obvious.

Answer (score 5):

Why not filter to check for truthyness and then join?

```
const concatObject = (obj, separator) =>
    Object.values(obj)
        .filter((val) => val)
        .join(separator);


let myAddress = {
    street1: '123 Happy St',
    street2: undefined,
    city: null,
    state: 'DC',
    zip: '20003'
}

concatObject(myAddress, ', ')
```

```
> "123 Happy St, DC, 20003"
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any chance for a change in this behavior in future ECMAScript versions?

I would say the chances are very slim. And there are several reasons:

### We already know what ES5 and ES6 look like

The future ES versions are already done or in draft. Neither one, afaik, changes this behavior. And the thing to keep in mind here is that it will take years for these standards to be established in browsers in the sense that you can write applications with these standards without relying on proxy tools that compile it to actual Javascript.

Just try to estimate the duration. Not even ES5 is fully supported by the majority of browsers out there and it will probably take another few years. ES6 is not even fully specified yet. Out of the blue, we are looking at at least another five years.

### Browsers do their own things

Browsers are known to make their own decisions on certain topics. You don't know whether all browsers will fully support this feature in exactly the same way. Of course you would know once it is part of the standard, but as of now, even if it was announced to become part of ES7, it would only be speculation at best.

And browsers may make their own decision here especially because:

### This change is breaking

One of the biggest things about standards is that they *usually* try to be backwards compatible. This is *especially* true for the web where the same code has to run on all kinds of envrionments.

If the standard introduces a new feature and it's not supported in old browsers, that's one thing. Tell your client to update their browser to use the site. But if you update your browser and suddenly half the internet breaks for you, that's a bug uhm-no.

Sure, this particular change is unlikely to break a lot of scripts. But that's usually a poor arguments because a standard is universal and has to take every chance into account. Just consider

```
"use strict";
```

as the instruction to switch to strict mode. It goes to show huw much effort a standard puts into trying to make everything compatible, because they could've made strict mode the default (and even only mode). But with this clever instruction, you allow old code to run without a change and still can take advantage of the new, stricter mode.

Another example for backwards compatibility: the `===` operator. `==` is fundamentally flawed (though some people disagree) and it could've just changed its meaning. Instead, `===` was introduced, allowing old code to still run without breaking; at the same time allowing new programs to be written using a more strict check.

And for a standard to break compatibility, there has to be a very good reason. Which brings us to

### There is just no good reason

Yes, it bugs you. That's understandable. But ultimately, it is nothing that can't be solved *very easily*. Use `||`, write a function – whatever. You can make it work at almost no cost. So what is *really* the benefit for investing all the time and effort into analyzing this change which we know is breaking anyway? I just don't see the point.

Javascript has several weak points in its design. And it has increasingly become a bigger issue as the language became more and more important and powerful. But while there are very good reasons to change a lot of its design, *other things just arent't meant to be changed*.

---

**Disclaimer:** This answer is partly opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

To add null and '' they need to meet a minimum common type criterium which in this case is a string type.

null is converted to "null" for this reason and as they are string the two are concatenated.

The same happens with numbers:

4 + '' = '4'

as there is a string in there which can't be converted to any number, so the 4 will be converted to string instead.

Comment: I know the coalescence in JS, but it isn't sufficient to justify this. A null or undefined object could coalesce in an empty String, I don't see a problem with that. Do you see one?

Comment: I think you mean "criterion" (from the Greek for a standard or judgement), rather than "criterium" (the Latin equivalent, but usually only used in English for a type of bicycle race, actually taken from the French "critérium" for "competition")