# Global variable is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a global variable. The variable is equal to null.  `var a=null;` Then I write `a=a+"example"` in console. But output is null example. Why is it so ?

Comment: Because when you turn `null` into a string, it's `"null"`. If you want to start from nothing, just use an empty string - `""`.

Comment: well what did you expect?

Comment: For a better understanding, explain what do you expect

Comment: It because as it was null it data type is implicitly taken as string as u pass "example" to concat

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why `null` is it turned to string? We all observe that it turns to string but why? I think that is what the user is asking. There are other solutions to avoid this behaviour, but what is the explanation of this?

Comment: @vlaz ı tried empty string. So output is" undefinedexample". But I use for loop . for example var a = null;  for(.......){   a=a+"ex "   }  first output is "nullex" second output is  "nullex ex"  Why is first output nullex

Comment: @Ionut type coercion. You are using `+` and also have a string, so the variable will be coerced into a string and the resulting operation is concatenation. That's why if you do `5 + "5"` you get `"55"`, too.

Comment: @Vlaz, I know how, but why?

Comment: @Frontenddeveloper your variable was `undefined` if it turns into `"undefined` - it wasn't an empty string.

Comment: @vlaz   Friends , My english is bad so I can not express myself. sorry. My purpose is to clean the variable before the loop

Comment: @Frontenddeveloper if you concat with string it takes string type if number then with number type and so on see answer for explanation

Comment: @Ionut OK, why _what_? The answer to your question was "due to type coercion". Are you asking "why are variables coerced to a type"? Because if so, I'll counter that with "what ELSE would you do"? `5 + 5` is definitely `10` because it's mathematical addition. `"a" + "b"` would be `"ab"` because it's string concatenation, however, when you encounter `5 + "a"` what are you to do - add or concatenate? The answer is - do the operation that both types can participate in with a meaningful result. Which is concatenation. The values `null` and `undefined` aren't much different in that.

Comment: @Vlaz, and that should be the winning answer :) I tried to get an answer with meaning. Most of us know what something does, but little of us knows the explanation of the behaviour.

Comment: read more here: [ECMA 262 V 5.1 11.6.1 The Addition operator (`+`)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1)

Comment: I understand thanks for your interest

Comment: To answer the actual question:

It is so, because in JavaScript if you concatenate 2 or more variables and one of them is a string, all will be typecasted to string.

This works also with other types like false, undefined, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possibilities in javascript:

Option 1

```
var a; 
a=a+"example";
```

**output:**  "undefinedexample"

Option 2

```
var a=null; 
a=a+"example";
```

**output:**  "nullexample"

Option 3

```
var a=""; 
a=a+"example";
```

**output:**  "example"

As per your Question you need to define **third option**. bcz in javascript **null** and **""** both are different types.

For more ref [JavaScript String concatenation behavior with null or undefined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572016/javascript-string-concatenation-behavior-with-null-or-undefined-values)

Comment: thanks for your interest

Comment: @Frontenddeveloper :)

Comment: you do not explain something, rather than showing somehting. what happens, if you add a numer to `null`?

Comment: var a = null;

console.log(a+5); output : 5

Answer (score 1):

If You want to concatenate strings this way, You shouldn't assign null but an empty string. Value `null` will be changed to string `'null'` in your code.

Example:

```
var a = ''; 

for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    a = a + 'abc'; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1):

As you are concatenating it with string it turning out to be string see this example it adopts the datatype you assign it to be for the initial value was null

if you concat with string it takes string type if number then with number type and so on

```js
var s = null;

console.log(s+"example");
console.log(s+5);
console.log(s+17.5)
```

Comment: thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what u really expecting,according to your problem,i think you need to concatenate two string,if am correct you can use

```
var str1 = '';
var str2 = "example";
var res = str1.concat(str2);
```

instead of `null` you can use `''`

Comment: thanks for your interest