# Concatenate with Null Undefined not Working in Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to concatenate words and at same time, remove, null and undefined.
Currently still getting error in the image below. How would someone resolve this?

[javascript-string-concatenation-behavior-with-null-or-undefined-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572016/javascript-string-concatenation-behavior-with-null-or-undefined-values)

In the picture, one of the properties is saying

> TypeError: cannot read property of undefined

Its like it cannot even read the argument in first place, to apply the undefined filters, etc.

```
get copyFromDescription() {
    if (this.addressId == 0) {
        return 'Select';
    } else { return [this.apn, this.combinedAddress,this.addressType.addressTypeDescription].filter(Boolean).join('') }
}
```

**Data Value Picture**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
.filter(val => !!val)
```

Boolean is a type

and test for addressType being undefined with

```
this.addressType && this.addressType.addressTypeDescription

get copyFromDescription() {
    if (this.addressId == 0) {
        return 'Select';
    } else { return [this.apn, this.combinedAddress,this.addressType && this.addressType.addressTypeDescription].filter(val => !!val).join('') }
}
```

Comment: also placed a comment, for some reason in my data model, address Type exists, but did not get into the new object array, strange, I will try this out also

Comment: also, addessType is nullable member in my model, so when I initialized the model, without that member, its not even showing, thanks

Answer (score 0):

this.addressType is undefined. Therefore it can't get a value when trying to access the addressTypeDescription property.

Boolean is a type and not a test. This seems a bit more logical to me.

```js
get copyFromDescription() {
    if (this.addressId == 0) {
        return 'Select';
    } else { return [this.apn, this.combinedAddress,this.addressType.addressTypeDescription].filter(val => !!val).join('') }
}
```

but then you will still be stuck with the undefined error which needs to be tested for.

```js
get copyFromDescription() {
    if (this.addressId === 0) 
        return 'Select';
    else if (this.addressType) return [this.apn, this.combinedAddress, this.addressType.addressTypeDescription]
      .filter(val => !!val).join('');
    else return [this.apn, this.combinedAddress] // you cannot use addressType here
      .filter(val => !!val).join('');
}
```