# When looping over an array of objects and adding data to a variable, it always adds an null along with the data

Tags: javascript

I have a an array of objects, and when I am looping over it add adding a value to a variable, the variable always has an nullin it. I know its a pretty basic question, but stuck on why it adds the null and don't know how to stop it.

```js
(function() {
  let ds = [{
      Name: "A",
      Age: 1
    },
    {
      Name: "B",
      Age: 2
    },
    {
      Name: "C",
      Age: 3
    }
  ];
  let str = null;

  for (let i = 0; i < ds.length; i++) {
    if (ds[i].Name) {
      str += ds[i].Name + ",";
    }
  }
  console.log(str);
})();
```

It shows as null, A, B, C, and what I want it to show as A,B,C

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript String concatenation behavior with null or undefined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572016/javascript-string-concatenation-behavior-with-null-or-undefined-values)

Comment: Try running `null + "42"`. This should answer your question. Use an empty string initially, or better yet, `ds.map(e => e.Name).join(",")` since everything has a name or `ds.filter(e => e.Name !== undefined).map(e => e.Name).join(",")` if you do have undef `Name` keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value null is stringified to "null" - [ToString](http://es5.github.io/#x9.8) . if you initialize it with empty string, will work.

```js
(function() {
  let ds = [{
      Name: "A",
      Age: 1
    },
    {
      Name: "B",
      Age: 2
    },
    {
      Name: "C",
      Age: 3
    }
  ];
  let str = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < ds.length; i++) {
    if (ds[i].Name) {
      str += ds[i].Name + ",";
    }
  }
  console.log(str);
})();
```