# Displaying unlimited amount of undefined arrays, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, concatenation

Referring to: [JavaScript String concatenation behavior with null or undefined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572016/javascript-string-concatenation-behavior-with-null-or-undefined-values)

I tried to display an array created from infinite amount of array of objects and some arrays might be undefined.
Is there a nicer way of writing that.
My solution for that problem does not look professional.

```
const theFunction = () => {
    let EveryArrayGoesHere = []
    try {
        EveryArrayGoesHere = EveryArrayGoesHere.concat(array1, array2, array3 ...)
        if (EveryArrayGoesHere) {
            EveryArrayGoesHere = JSON.stringify(EveryArrayGoesHere)
            EveryArrayGoesHere = EveryArrayGoesHere.replace('null,', '')
            EveryArrayGoesHere = EveryArrayGoesHere.replace(',null', '')
            return JSON.parse(EveryArrayGoesHere);
        } else {
            return 'data not availible';
        }
    } catch (e) {
        if (e) {
            console.error('data error', e.message)
        }
    }
}
console.log('array of objects:',theFunction() )
```

Comment: Some of the arrays might be undefined or some of the objects?

Comment: arrays might be undefined, thanks

Comment: may arrays contain just undefined values i.e. [undefined, undefined] ...

Comment: the solution is for arrays that contain objects ` [
    {
        "product": "apple",
        "trueFalse": true,
        "price": 1.5
    },
    {
        "product": "banana",
        "trueFalse": true,
        "price": 1
    }] `
the solution might work for arrays with similar structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've correctly understood your question.

```js
var collector = [];
var data = [
  [1,2,3],
  undefined,
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8],
  undefined,
  [9]  
];
// console.log('data => ', data);
data = data.filter(v => { return Array.isArray(v)}).forEach(a => { collector = collector.concat(a) });
console.log('collector => ',collector);
```

Comment: ` Array.isArray ` do the job, thanks @Reflective