# Why "abc" + undefined is printing the output like this: abcundefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, undefined

I was printing `"abc" + undefined` and I got output like this: `abcundefined`. Why is the reason it output like this? is undefined kinda string? We can get similar result when running `"abc" + null`.

Comment: What result were you expecting?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572016/javascript-string-concatenation-behavior-with-null-or-undefined-values

Comment: string + something or something + string results in both operands being converted to string types. So it's effectively doing `String("abc") + String(undefined)`, and `String(undefined)` gives the string `"undefined"` ([ref](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator))

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `+` operator is used for both `concatenation` and `addition`. If you use `+` operator with a string type value, then the return value will automatically be converted to string type even if there is any others type of data.

Example 1:
console.log("abc" + undefined);

Output:
abcundefined

Example 2:
console.log("hello" + true);

Output:
hellotrue